# How to access the properties of a subview of a custom class UIView?

Tags: ios, uiview, properties, overriding

### OBJECTIVE

I have a custom class UIView that we are going to call `ContainerView`. The custom class also defines another UIView, that we can call `presentingView`.

**I want to create a relation between the size of `ContainerView.view` and `presenting.view`**: every time the frame/size of one view is set up, the frame/size of the other is updated.

### HALFWAY SOLUTION

I am able to do update presentingView.frame when ContainerView.view.frame is set/updated:

```
class ContainerView: UIView {  
    var presentingView: UIView!
    override var frame: CGRect {
        didSet {
            presentingView.size = CGSize(width: frame.width * 3, height: frame.height * 3)
        }
    }
}
```

### QUESTION

Is there a way to likewise access `presentingView.frame` property and use a `didSet` to update `ContainerView.view.size` ?

Thanks for your kind help

Comment: Is there any reason you can not set auto layout for those 2 views so they have identical size?

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Ryan. They don't necessarily have the same size, just a pre-defined size relation depending on another property of the custom class, but your suggestion could apply anyway. I don't see why it would not be doable, yet, it is not the solution I am looking for. The 2 views won't share any other constraints but the size and I don't want to mess up with the auto-layout constraints by multiplying them.